# Do I need SSL when communicating between Google App Engine apps?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two App Engine apps that need to communicate with each other. I am not using modules.

I use HTTP url fetch to communicate between them. Do I need to make the requests HTTPS to ensure secure communication.

I seem to remember an article stating that all communication within Google's infrastructure is encrypted/secure by default, therefore making HTTPS redundant.

Can anyone confirm this as it would be good to save some valuable CPU clock cycles with zero effort?

(I know how to ensure the identity of each server using the HTTP Headers so identity is not a problem.)

Comment: I don't think there is a guarantee that your traffic within Google's infrastructure is automatically secure/encrypted. It may just be that Google is now using HTTPS (or similar) for all communication between/in datacenters for its own services, not yours (why wasted double encrypting traffic on the switch level if existing services were encrypted?) You can guarantee the security yourself by utilizing HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of SSL is to keep some hacker from sniffing your requests/responses to steal valuable info, like your online identity.  A call from one Google server to another should not be exposed to any sniffing.  Thus, in my opinion, SSL between Google instances is unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not sure you have any sort of guarantee that your traffic should not be exposed to sniffing. Google has a lot of security experts, but it doesn't mean they are invincible...

Comment: It's my opinion that SSL is not needed between Google instances as well. I just want to see if anyone has a link to some hard facts so I can know for certain that communication between instances will completely remain within the Google intranet.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is not necessary if you set the follow_redirects parameter to False when invoking fetch. This will ensure the call will not leave Google’s infrastructure. Please see **Making requests to another App Engine app or Google service** section of [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Making_requests) document.

On the other hand using SSL will not increase instance's CPU clock cycles, but the request-response will take a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the link. `follow_redirects` does not specifically refer to http or https though. It doesn't answer if sending data between apps using http could be susceptible to man in the middle attacks. (I am pretty certain as you suggest that HTTP is fine though. I just want documented proof of this from Google.)

Comment: @Dan An official indication of traffic encryption is the statement from Google’s Chief Legal Officer available [here](http://allthingsd.com/20131030/how-the-nsa-may-be-tapping-yahoos-and-googles-fiber-optic-cables/). Another report traffic is encrypted is [here](http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/technology/google-encrypts-data-amid-backlash-against-nsa-spying/2013/09/06/9acc3c20-1722-11e3-a2ec-b47e45e6f8ef_story.html).